# Permanently set environmental variables in /home/user/.profile

Tags: environment-variables, aix

I have this issue. It will be appreciated all your ideas. I need to set some environmental variables permanently for a user. I tried to edit `/home/user/.profile`, but it doesn't load when I log in. I'm running AIX Version 7.1. Example of `.profile`:

```
LIBPATH=$ODBCHOME/lib:$INFA_JDK_HOME/jre/bin:$INFA_JDK_HOME/jre/bin/classic:/usr/lib:$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:$LIBPATH
export LIBPATH

INFA_JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1024m"
export INFA_JAVA_OPTS

export pm_service=PCIS_NAL_DEV_SVC
export pm_domain=DOM_NAL_DEV
export pm_user=ETL_Execution

INFA_DEFAULT_DATABASE_PASSWORD=hYatVAbvv72gqs6d6KnGMde6I093xjiRQgoL53iWjbw=
export INFA_DEFAULT_DATABASE_PASSWORD

PM_ADMIN=Dp884g2D8cu9TM7A2PgiLg==
export PM_ADMIN

umask 022

if [ -s "$MAIL" ]           # This is at Shell startup.  In normal
    then echo "$MAILMSG"    # operation, the Shell checks
fi                          # periodically.
```

---

thanks

Comment: I've run this command to change to super user..
(pespitia) nalunix17:/home/pespitia $ sudo -u etladmin bash
then i run this... (etladmin) :/home/pespitia  cat /etc/passwd | grep etladmin
and i got etladmin:!:30010:1::/home/etladmin:/usr/bin/ksh